# Filereading vs Message Queues

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, message-queue, performance-testing

I have a question related to performance,

Scenario: 
I have a product where 2 applications(hosted on System A and B respectively) are interacting and passing information to each other.

**Approach 1:**
The way I have achieved this is using a static local file created in System B. System B is running Apache. App in System A invokes a PHP file hosted in System B and that PHP files writes the information into local file in System B. Then App running in System B reads that file and processes that information.

**Approach 2:** I can create a message queue probably RabbitMQ in another System C and have Apps in System A and B poll that message queue and interact with each other.

Now performance comparison
Point 1: Communication from System A to B in either case is over network so i am not worried about that, the diff might be only slight

Point 2: In 1st approach app in System A is reading local file , while in 2nd approach its reading message queue from network.

Even though I understand that message queue will make my system much more robust, however performance is my 1st priority and hence I am ready to make necessary sacrifices.

Please suggest, in above Point 2: reading local file is more performance intensive or reading message queue online.

Comment: Why introduce a 3rd system to host the message queue? Why not put it on one of your existing servers? Redis may be a nice option, btw.

Comment: So you are saying that message broker is more efficient than file reading?

Comment: That is what I would try first. Mosquitto is pretty simple to rig up a test and measure.

Comment: What about RabbitMQ?